# 10060 error in WSASend while sending data to the server?

Tags: c++

I am getting this 10060 error while sending data to the server. It freezes for sometime and i am getting this 10060 when i try WSASend. Can anyone help what is the reason?

Comment: http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedsocketoptionioctl7.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the socket send timeout. However, if it's problems with the connection, then there is not much you can do. If the freeze is always 45 seconds, it's a sign that the connection is broken (at least it was 45 seconds some years ago when I last did socket programming on Windows.)

Comment: Freezing period before this error is sometimes 20 minutes and sometimes 3-4 minutes. It is not constant. I am creating a socket once and sending continuously , whenever there is a problem i reconnect , but problem is it freezes for before this error.

Comment: @Ershad Is the socket blocking or non-blocking? If it's blocking, then maybe it's just that the server doesn't reply in a long while?

Comment: Yes, Its blocking socket, so what is the solution to make it properly running without freezing period.

Comment: @Ershad Have you tried changing the send-timeout (`setsockopt` with `SO_SNDTIMEO`)? Does it help?

Comment: i have set this timeout as 10000 milliseconds with SO_SNDTIMEO in setsockopt, is that a problem? Can i increase to 90000, will it affect performance?

Comment: @Ershad The `10060` error code is `WSAETIMEDOUT`, which is what you should get after a timeout of `WSASend`. If the time is longer than you set with `SO_SNDTIMEO` there is some other error which I can't help you with. Sorry!